# MobileFirst 8 (MFP 8) unauthorized access to protected javascript adapter resources and no challenge was created from UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Just start using MFP 8, and have created a UserLogin security check referring to [user authentication - security check](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/user-authentication/security-check/) and created the scope `access-resticted` mapping to the UserLogin security check.

The UserLogin is used to protect my javascript adapter resources like:

```
< procedure name="getData" scope="access-restricted"/ >
```

But when calling my resources `getData` got unauthorized error, and there is no challenge created by the UserLogin security check.

Expecting the following code to be executed:

```java
@Override
protected Map<String, Object> createChallenge() {
    System.out.println("---------------------CREATE-CHALLENGE---------------------");
    Map<String, Object> challenge = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    challenge.put("errorMsg", errorMsg);
    return challenge;
}

@Override
protected boolean validateCredentials(Map<String, Object> credentials) 
{
    if(credentials!=null && credentials.containsKey("username") && credentials.containsKey("password"))
        {
            String username = credentials.get("username").toString();
            String password = credentials.get("password").toString();
            if(!username.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty() && username.equals(password)) 
                {
                    userId = username;
                    displayName = username;

                    //Optional RememberMe
                    if(credentials.containsKey("rememberMe") )
                        {
                            rememberMe = Boolean.valueOf(credentials.get("rememberMe").toString());
                        }                
                     return true;
                }
            else 
                {
                    errorMsg = "Wrong Credentials";
                }
        }
    else
        {
            errorMsg = "Credentials not set properly";
        }
    return false;
}
```

Also tried to execute the adapter resource from MobileFirst-Swagger, turn on the security check, and was prompt for username & password. When answer the challenge is always incorrect username & password, but based on the code above, the validateCredential as long as username.equal(password) then should be valid, but it's still invalid when test from Swagger.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you mapped the "access-restricted" to UserLogin SecurityCheck in security settings for the application registration?

Comment: Yes. It was mapped.

Comment: Could it because i commented the "<JAXRSApplicationClass>" in UserLogin adapter.xml ? Any relation? The reason i commented because it causing error when building the adapter. [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017012516:build (default-build) on project MyJavaAdapter: Adapter xml file schema validation encountered errors: [cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'JAXRSApplicationClass'. One of '{securityCheckDefinition}' is expected.] -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is failing to map `UserLogin` security check to `access-restricted` scope in security configurations of the application in MFP console.

Following are the steps:

- Go to Security Tab of your App in MFP Console
- Map `access-restricted` scope to `UserLogin` security check as shown below in Scope-Elements Mapping Section

[image]

More details on Scope Mapping can be found [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/#scope-mapping).

Comment: The scope mapping was created.

Comment: @Amon Please share wireshark network capture between your server and client.